# Error: "Maximum number of iterations exceeded" using nlcom in Stata

Tags: stata, standard-error

I am trying to estimate the standard error of marginal effects using `nlcom` in Stata (Delta method) for the limited dependent variable model . We normally compute the probability, conditional, and unconditional parts when computing the marginal effect. I was also able to obtain the standard errors for conditional and unconditional part using `nlcom` in Stata. However, I got the error "maximum number of iterations exceeded" when using `nlcom` for probability. I did look at the solution [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2009-03/msg01244.html) and it did solve for some of the binary variables (3). However, I still get the same error for 4 variables. I dig into the problem and find that the error is associated with part where the dummy variable is 0 :

\begin{equation}
\Delta P(y>0)= P(y>0|x=1)-P(y>0|x=0)
\end{equation}

Here is the sample code for the race variable (dummy variable) for which the `nlcom` works for the part where dummy variable is 1 (without correction) but not for with 0 even after taking into account the correction suggested in the website mentioned earlier. Increasing the iterations and multiplying by larger magnitudes also didn't help:

```
       _nl_1:  binormal(1.733373263151318-(.0438395852394023*[Tier1]_b[race])+(1*[Tier1]_b[race]),7.575546508411257-(.0438395852394023*[Tier2]_b[race])+
> (1*[Tier2]_b[race])/exp([lnsigma]_b[_cons]),tanh([tau]_b[_cons]))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _nl_1 |   .9223902   .0129743    71.09   0.000     .8969611    .9478193
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       _nl_1:  binormal(1.733373263151318-(.0438395852394023*[Tier1]_b[race])+(0*[Tier1]_b[race]),7.575546508411257-(.0438395852394023*[Tier2]_b[race])+
> (0*[Tier2]_b[race])/exp([lnsigma]_b[_cons]),tanh([tau]_b[_cons]))*(1e+2)
Maximum number of iterations exceeded.
```

Any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the source of your problem, but in both the successful and unsuccessful `nl` statement, the estimated standard deviation, `exp([lnsigma]_b[_cons])`, divides only the last `[Tier*]_b[race]` term, and then  only in the second argument of `binormal`(this perhaps because you constrained the SD to be `1` in the first argument). Here's a guess at what you meant in the second `nl` statement, but it's just a guess.

```
 #delim ;   
_nl_1:
 binormal
((1.733373263151318-(.0438395852394023*[Tier1]_b[race])+(0*[Tier1]_b[race]))
/exp([lnsigma]_b[_cons]),
 (7.575546508411257-(.0438395852394023*[Tier2]_b[race])+ (0*[Tier2]_b[race]))
/exp([lnsigma]_b[_cons]),
tanh([tau]_b[_cons])) ;
#delim cr
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. But, that is not the problem. The formula is `binormal(x1b*,x2b*/sigma,rho)`. So, my expression is correct.

Comment: Yes, but the second argument as written in your question is of the form _k_ y2* + _d_ (y2*/sigma) : only part is divided by sigma.

Comment: Awesome Steve. Now, the problem is solved with corrections. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are very welcome. These complicated expressions are a lot easier to check if you make them multi-line, as I did, so that parallel parts line up. I find that doing this with delim ; makes for cleaner code having lots of lines ending in ///'.  This practice is also useful for writing plot statements that have lots of options.